# Move values from one column to another in datatable

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, multiple-columns

I am generating a datatable dynamically from different values e.g. list and bind it to a radgridview.

Please consider the below input (displayed in radgridview)

```
col1|col2
---------
A   |  D
A   |  D
B   |  D
B   |  E
C   |  E
D   |
```

The above output is wrong because D is in two columns i.e. col1 and col2.

I want output in below format.

```
col1|col2
---------
A   |  D
A   |  D
B   |  D
B   |  D
C   |  E
    |  E
```

see above output of gridview, i.e now D is moved to another column to follow the sequence. Same way I want to move the values between columns that whatever the words are but "starting with same letter" should be under a same column.

Can anyone help me out with this. Any C# or vb.net code can help.

Please note that datatable can have n no. of columns and rows generated dynamically.

Comment: Columns in RadGrid are designed to be data columns, similar to columns in a SQL database.  They are not designed for this use.  You may want to consider some other control (or multiple RadGrid controls) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode (in C#) might be:

```
String sql = String.Empty;
String candidateDataValue = // assign it from wherever
if ((candidateDateValue.StartsWith('A') ||
    (candidateDateValue.StartsWith('B') ||
    (candidateDateValue.StartsWith('CA'))
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE (col1) VALUES (:candidateDataValue");
}
else
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE (col2) VALUES (:candidateDataValue");
}
// Now insert the record using "sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert and sort values in a column?

I think youre using the wrong data structure to do that. A DataTable should be use for "tables".

I consider you should create a class with `List<List<string>>` object on it. It will have the behaviour you want. Removing from one "column", adding to another and sort the whole list.

```
List<List<string>> Table;

//Table Filled  with
col1|col2
---------
A   |  D
A   |  D
B   |  D
B   |  E
C   |  E
D   |

var str = Table[0][5];
Table[0].removeAt[5];
Table[1].add(str);
Table[1].Sort();
```

Result:

```
col1|col2
---------
A   |  D
A   |  D
B   |  D
B   |  D
C   |  E
    |  E
```

**Update:**

If you need the `DataTable` Object to fill some kind of property. You can create a parse function to create a `DataTable` using a `List< List<string> >` as parameter.